# JSON parsing issue from the hidden text field

Tags: jquery, json

I have following JSON string saved in the input hidden field,

```
[{"pro":{"draft":{"create":"1"},"submitted":{"edit":"1","delete":"0"}},"ind":{"draft":{"create":""},"submitted":{"edit":"","delete":""}}}]
```

When I am trying to retrieve JSON from the hidden text field like,

```
JSON.stringify($('#SecurityJSON').val()) //returns "[{"
```

But if try directly passing field contents into JSON stringify then it returns proper JSON,

```
JSON.stringify([{"pro":{"draft":{"create":"1"},"submitted":{"edit":"1","delete":"0"}},"ind":{"draft":{"create":""},"submitted":{"edit":"","delete":""}}}]) //works well
```

Do I need to parse/format text field to retrieve correct JSON ?

Comment: Did you properly escape the `"` the value of the input?

Comment: Thanks for pointing. It was one of the issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var data = {}
data = $.parseJSON($('#SecurityJSON').val());
console.log(data[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value='[{"pro":{"draft":{"create":"1"},"submitted":{"edit":"1","delete":"0"}},"ind":{"draft":{"create":""},"submitted":{"edit":"","delete":""}}}]'
    id="SecurityJSON">
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !